# OWIN - token based authentication on classic MVC web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

To be honest, I don't seem to grasp OWIN concept very well - this is the first library I simply can't seem to understand no matter what I try :(

Now to the problem...

I have two MVC apps - one that uses WebAPI and one that don't. WebAPI app uses token based authentication and it works, right now I'm trying to implement authentication in second (non WebAPI) app and I don't know how to do it. I tried using the token code from WebAPI app, but then I realised that token generator can't be called directly in MVC controller, so I ended up with something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel loginData)
{
    string baseUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

    string resultContent = "";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", loginData.grant_type),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("company", loginData.company),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", loginData.password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", loginData.username)
        });

        var result = client.PostAsync("/token", content).Result;
        resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }

    string access_token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(resultContent).access_token;
    if(TempData.Keys.Contains("Token"))
    {
        TempData.Remove("Token");
    }
    TempData.Add("Token", access_token);

    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Token", access_token);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

    HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(cookie);

    if(loginData.fromUrl != null)
    {
        return Redirect(String.Format("{0}{1}", baseUrl, loginData.fromUrl));
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect(String.Format("{0}", baseUrl));
    }
}
```

(While the above works it's ugly as hell - not to mention error prone.)

Then I struggled, how to inject token into every request made by controller, I ended with something like this:

```
protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var token = this.Request.Cookies["Token"].Value;

    this.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", token));

    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```

But it doesn't seems to work. I don't know if my approach is correct (looking at it now - it's probably not...) - so the questions are:

1. Should token based approach be used at all with non WebAPI, MVC apps?
2. If so - is there a better way to do this, or do I really need to write "spaghetti code" like the one above just to simply generated access token? I'm trying to use it to have one universal authentication approach, instead of many - but perhaps cookie based approach should be used instead?
3. I'm trying to use it to have one universal authentication approach, instead of many - but perhaps cookie based approach should be used instead?

I tried following OWIN tutorials as well as build in MVC applications, but didn't find single example of mixing token with classic web app - unless we count AngularJS tutorials, which sadly don't apply here.

Answer (score 1):

I think a cookie based approach is more apt. You are doing way too much work than needed, as you already noticed. Have a look at the AAD samples, they are a really good starting point for using owin for authentication. Particularly, I would recommend taking a look at https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet, `ToDoListService` is a WebAPI project and uses token based authentication, `ToDoListWebApp` is non WebAPI project that uses cookie based approach. There are lot of other samples too in that repo that might be of your interest.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, and sorry for my very late response, we have decided to go with completely different approach - now we will by trying to map IdentityUser to our User tables and use built-in Owin UserManger... unfortunately this appears to be another hard thing to do, since - for example - we simply don't currently use claims, so OWIN complains about that - but that's a story for different question :)